# How enable IIS Windows Authentication ONLY within a domain?

Tags: php, windows, authentication, iis, server

I've an PHP website in IIS. For this website I have disabled the Anonomous Authentication and I have enabled the Windows Authentication.
This is working well: when users are in my domain and the site is a trusted site in IE, the users don't see any popup, because they are in the domain, and with my website I can read their Windows username.

But when they visit my site outside the domain, they get an authentication popup. How can I disable this popup for all users **outside** the domain (so they all are anonomous)?

Comment: Most site owners would set up an anonymous version of the site and forward users outside to that special version for sake.